# What are the odds of flipping a coin 100 times and seeing HHHHT?

Tags: probability

What are the odds of flipping a coin 100 times and seeing exactly four consecutive heads? Any more than four heads in a row, such as "HHHHH" would not be considered a string of four consecutive heads. Seeing 10 sets of "HHHHT" would allow a max of 20 consecutive patterns. How would you expect to find the number of times an isolated string of exactly 4 heads in a row in $n$ coin flips?

Comment: I don't understand, you seem to ask many questions at once.

Comment: Is your question the expected number of times you would expect to find $HHHHT$ in a sequence of $100$ flips?

Comment: I flip a coin 100 times. How many times should I see HHHH? A HHHHH or anything greater will not be considered as a HHHH.

Comment: No just HHHHT but THHHHT

Comment: I am pretty sure the question is "Suppose I flip a coin 100 times. How many subsequences of exactly four heads in a row (no more or less) should I expect to see?"

Comment: The title is frankly misleading, please modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any sequence of $100$ flips, “mark” each spot $HHHH$ occurs (and occurs not within a longer run of $H$’s) between the middle $H$’s. For example, the sequence $$HHTHHHTTTHHHHTHT\dots TTHHHHHTHTHHTTHHHH$$ would be marked $${HHTHHHTTTHH}^{\color{red}|\!}{HHTHT\dots TTHHHHHTHTHHTTHH}^{\color{red}|\!}{HH}^{}.$$

Among the $97$ positions where marks could occur (from after the first two flips to before the final two), a mark does appear in each of the $2^{\rm nd}$ through $96^{\rm th}$ ($95$ in all) of those spots (as $THH^{\color{red}|\!}HHT$) with probability $\frac{1}{2^6}$ (the chance the surrounding sequence of six flips is $THHHHT$). In the first and last positions, the probability is $\frac{1}{2^5}$ (the chance of $HH^{\color{red}|\!}HHT$ for position $1$ and $THH^{\color{red}|\!}HH$ for position $97$).

By the linearity of expectation, the expected number of marks is $95\cdot\frac1{2^6}+2\cdot\frac1{2^5}=\frac{99}{64}$.

[Added] It may be easier to focus on the $H$’s and $T$’s instead of the spaces between them, so another way to mark the runs-of-$4$ is to color in red the last $H$ of each run, like $$HHTHHHTTTHHH\color{red}HTHT\dots TTHHHHHTHTHHTTHHH\color{red}H.$$ The first three $H$’s are colored red with probability $0$, the fourth with probability $\frac{1}{2^5}$, the next $95$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^6}$, and the last with probability $\frac{1}{2^5}$, giving the same result.

Comment: Is it possible for you to let me know what the answer would be for 8 out of 100?

Comment: Try to modify my answer for runs of $8$. There are no new situations that come up, so it shouldn’t be very hard.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to fall easily to linearity of expectation. Let $a_1,a_2\dots a_n$ be your sequence of outcomes.

Let $X_1$ be the indicator variable that $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4=H$ and $a_5=T$

Let $X_{97}$ be the indicator variable that $a_{96}=T$ and $a_{97},a_{98},a_{99},a_{100}=H$

Finally, for $2\leq n \leq 96$ let $X_n$ be the indicator that $a_{n-1}=T,a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},a_{n+3}=H,a_{n+4}=T$

The random variable you want is $\sum_{i=1}^{97} X_n$.

By linearity of expectation its expectation is $E[X_1]+95E[X_2]+E[X_{97}]=\frac{1}{32}+\frac{95}{64}+\frac{1}{32}=\frac{99}{64}$

Comment: Would this factor in the possibility of 10 heads in a row that would change you 100 coin flips into 90. From the start you should automatically drop the 100 flips down to 50 with the assumption that the other 50 flips would be tails correct? What are the odds of 5 heads or 6 heads each one of those will take more flips away from what you need to achieve 4 heads.

Comment: What I answered is the expected number of times you can find a substring of the form $HHHH$ that does not have another $H$ to either side. Assuming the flips are independent, and each outcome has probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Therefore I should expect how many strings of 4 out of 100?

Comment: Also how many HHH should I expect out of 100? I will gladly tip you for this information.

Comment: When they are four $H$ it is $\frac{99}{64}$ and when there are three It is $\frac{1}{16}+\frac{96}{32}+\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: You believe that out of 100 flips there will only be two sets of THHHT?

Comment: On average yes, so if you look at all of them and count how many there are in total and divide by $2^{100}$ you get $\frac{99}{64}$

Comment: How about 10 consecutive heads out of 100?

Comment: then it is $\frac{1}{2^{11}}+\frac{89}{2^{12}}+\frac{1}{2^{11}}$

Comment: So how many times should I see it out of 10000 for instance. I'm sorry for asking for answer to seemingly simple questions I'm more of a theory guy than a math guy.

Comment: if you throw $10000$ times then you should get $10$ consecutive (and not more) an expected number of $\frac{1}{2^{11}}+\frac{9989}{2^{12}}+\frac{1}{2^{11}}$

Comment: Which is 1 in how many

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How many times will you see 10 head coin flips in a row out of 10000? You showed me a math problem. I don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: I told you, $\frac{1}{2^{11}}+\frac{9989}{2^{12}}+\frac{1}{2^{11}}$, which is approximately $2.43$

Comment: I think there is a problem with the calculation, in that it assumes $X_1$, $X_2$ etc are independent. But they are not - if $X_3$ is 1 then $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_4$ to $X_7$ must be zero. So you cannot simply add the expectations of the indicator variables.

Comment: You don't need variables to be independent to apply lineality of expectation. It's not like when you calculate the probability that two events happen or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

For $i=1$ to $97$, let random variable $X_i$ be equal to $1$ if there is a string of HHHH that begins at $i$ and does not extend, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. We want the expectation of $X_1+\cdots+X_{97}$. By the linearity of expectation, this is $E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_{97})$.

So we need only calculate the $\Pr(X_i)=1$.

These are not all equal. If $i=1$ or $i=97$, we have $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{32}$. For all the other $i$, we have $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{64}$. That is because in all but "end" cases, the string of $4$ H must be flanked by T on both sides.

The required expectation is therefore $2\cdot \frac{1}{32}+95\cdot\frac{1}{64}$.

Comment: Would this factor in the possibility of 10 heads in a row that would change you 100 coin flips into 90. From the start you should automatically drop the 100 flips down to 50 with the assumption that the other 50 flips would be tails correct? What are the odds of 5 heads or 6 heads each one of those will take more flips away from what you need to achieve 4 heads.

Comment: The expectation calculation (indirectly) takes care of $10$ heads in a row by not counting them, because then $X_i=0$ for $i=1$ to at least $11$.